# Selecting elements from a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Being a novice, I'm having trouble with the following:
I have a list of lists and want only those elements where the second element of the second level is positive. So, for example, from

```
list1={{1,-1},{12,4},{8,-6},{2,2},{3,-1},{4,4}}
```

I want to get

```
list2={{12,4},{2,2},{4,4}}
```

I know that it has to be easy, but I've tried

```
list2=Select[list1,list1[[1,2]]]>0
```

I've tried setting `list2={{},{}}` and then

```
For[j=1,j<=Length[list1],j++,If[list1[[j,2]]>0,Append[list2,list1[[j]]]]]
```

and a few things that I've forgotten. I know that it has to be easy but I've spent an hour on it and am out of patience!

Comment: `Select[list1, #[[2]] > 0 &]`

Comment: Just that easy. Thanks! If you (or anyone) has a moment, I'd like to understand why my first attempt, i.e., Select[list1,list1[[1,2]]>0, fails.

Comment: Just for fun: `Pick[#, UnitStep@#[[All, 2]], 1] &@list1`

Comment: Also `Select[Last /* Positive] @ list1`

Answer (score 9):

A bit too long for a comment.
Your first attempt `Select[list1,list1[[1,2]]>0]` (I assumed that there is closing bracket in the end) doesn't fail, it does a different thing though. [Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) takes a boolean function for its second argument. This function is being applied to all elements of your list and if evaluates as `True` the element is selected.
When you plugged `list[[1,2]]>0` in place of that test function you get always `False` because your `list1[[1,2]]` equals $-1$. 
The `Select[list1, #[[2]] > 0 &]` has [a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) in the second place. The `#[[2]] > 0 &` means following: check if second element of your argument is greater than $0$.

Regarding `For` loop attempt, don't even try to use `For`, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica/134610?noredirect=1#comment363765_134610) is why.

Comment: in addition to @BlacKow 's answer I would like to say that you can use `Pick[list1, Thread[list1[[All, 2]] > 0], True]` if you want to operate the boolean logic on the list prior to selecting the elements

Comment: Thank you BlacKow and Al Hashmi, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Rob - while we're listing equivalent ways to do it, my first thought would be something like `Cases[list1, {_, a_ /; a > 0}]`